# Will sudo inside another virtual environment screw up my other python packages in another virtual environment?

Tags: python, linux, sudo, python-venv

If I want to install OpenCV and need third-party dependencies for it, like `Sudo apt-get install CMake gfortran` in a virtualenvironment named 'venv2'. Will this sudo later screw up my other package say Tensorflow ver: 1.15 in another virtual environment 'venv1'?

Other list of commands:

```
`sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-numpy
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev libgif-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libcanberra-gtk*
$ sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libgtk-3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libtbb2 libtbb-dev libdc1394-22-dev libv4l-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev libatlas-base-dev libblas-dev`
```

Comment: Using `apt-get`, you aren't doing anything with or to the virtual environment at all.

Comment: how about other commands that i updated to my post? Im relatively new with this thanks. Also isn't numpy involved in running other stuff? Will numpy versions conflict if I have Tensorflow and Opencv installed in the same virtual env?

Comment: If they are sharing globally installed code, yes, there is a potential for conflict. Python virtual environments only help you isolate *Python* packages, not the code they may call out to.

Comment: what would you advice for best practices to avoid such conflicts?

Comment: You need something like Docker or Nix, because none of these requirements are *Python* packages.